# Admob - Banner ads not showing after few days deploy

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I think I carefully read and understand admob implementation instructions.
It works really well with test ads when developing. But when I deploy it to market with real app unit id, it returns nothing, shows nothing. When debugging I get `onAdFailedToLoad()` Code 3 which is `ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL` means "The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.", its been a week since I release to play store.

I have a problem with admob the other day, my previous admob account got terminated because invalid traffic which I did not do anything to artificially increase ads impression, etc. so I remove admob from my apps and create apps version 2 with new admob account, but with the same apps.

Could be the problem is google admob disabled your apps too(not only your admob account) so when you create new account but with same apps, your apps won't display any ads because your apps is disabled from admob service?

Code snippet:

gradle:

```
//firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'

//admob
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
```

manifest:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="[ADMOB_APP_ID]"/>
```

`Main.java` code:

```
@BindView(R.id.adView)
AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
MobileAds.initialize(this, ADMOB_APP_ID);
adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
...
}
```

`activity_main.xml` code:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="[Banner_Unit_Id]" />
```

Or am I doing anything wrong with the code?

Comment: ads service using lower version and try that. implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'

Comment: By the way, you don't need firebase for AdMob.

Answer (score 1):

May this helps you :-

Actually you have to add the test device id when you are working with the debug build in AdRequest.

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder() 
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")  // Your Test Device Id
        .build();
```

Otherwise it will can't display until your app will goes for live.